# Tools for measuring empirical computational complexity of Java codes?

Tags: java, complexity-theory

I have a few Java codes for which I wish to measure empirical computational complexity . There is a [trend-prof](http://trend-prof.tigris.org/) tool which takes as input compiled `C/C++` programs .

Are there similar tools to the trend-prof that take as an input compiled Java programs ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sonar is commonly used : http://www.sonarsource.org/

Regards.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. I'm trying to check over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390310/does-sonar-have-computational-complexity-measuring-capabilities

Comment: I agree. Plain sonar is AFAIK not able to do this. There might be a plugin, but the answer is at best incomplete.

Comment: Of course you have to eventually activate/install plugins, but that goes without saying when you are using sonar :) . You will find plenty of them reference in sonar documentation: [http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+Library](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+Library)

Comment: So which plugin provides computational complexity analysis for Java? I can not find any reference to one myself.