# Does Sonar have computational complexity measuring capabilities?

Tags: java, complexity-theory, sonarqube

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007327/tools-for-measuring-empirical-computational-complexity-of-java-codes) asking how to measure [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) of Java code similar to what [trend-prof](http://trend-prof.tigris.org/) does for C/C++. The accepted answer to that question says it is commonly done using [Sonar](https://www.sonarqube.org/). I know that Sonar has good [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) capabilities built in, but that is not what the question was asking for.

Does Sonar in fact have computational complexity measuring capabilities?

If so any pointers to details on setting it up would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there aren't any similar tools for Java integrated in Sonarqube. Like the comments point out the answer confuses "computational complexity" with "cyclometric complexity".

There are also no plugins for sonar, that I know of, that add these metrics. Maybe there is some project somewhere but at least in the official plugin repository is nothing that does that.